# Election page's candidate count still counts withdrawn candidates

Tags: bug, election

Stack Overflow is currently undergoing an election period. It originally had six candidates, but one was withdrawn using the [new functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979/223467) introduced back in March (details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412472/2422776)).

There seems to be a minor UI bug with this process, though. While one of the candidates was withdrawn, the counter at the top of the page was not updated. In the current Stack Overflow election, it still shows six candidates while there are clearly only five you can vote for.

[image]

Comment: Also posted on Meta Stack Overflow: [Candidate count has not been updated since one candidate was withdrawn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412483/208273)